# How to get noweb and listings to cooperate?

Tags: listings, latex-misc, literate-programming

The introduction of the Linux subsystem for Windows has made it possible 
again to use noweb (https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/) under Windows. I'd like to pretty-print the resulting code, for which arguably the listings package is the method of choice.

```
% -*- TeX:UK -*-
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[british,pdftex,twoside,12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%suitable for most modern operating systems
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,%foreign language support
            xcolor,%handle colours
            css-colors,%defines named web-safe colors
            listings,%typeset computer code
            noweb}%support for literate programming
\frenchspacing
\selectlanguage{british}
\lstloadlanguages{Pascal}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{Cornsilk},
        language=[Borland6]Pascal,
        numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,
        }
\title{Example}
\author{Engelbert Buxbaum }
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
@
\maketitle
\abstract{Noweb is a simple to use system for literate programming. It 
is suitable for all programming languages, but has no
pretty-printing capabilities. Listings can pretty-print, but has no 
literate programming ability. A combination of both would be ideal. }
The example code is:
\begin{lstlisting}
<<*>>=
program HelloWorld;
begin
  write('Hello, World');
  readln;
end
@
\end{lstlisting}
Unfortunately, the output is not what was intended.
\end{document}
```

`noweave -delay test.nw > test.tex` produces the following LaTeX-code (critical piece only):

```
\begin{lstlisting}
\nwenddocs{}\nwbegincode{2}\moddef{*}\endmoddef\nwstartdeflinemarkup
\nwenddeflinemarkup
program HelloWorld;
begin
  write('Hello, World');
  readln;
end
\nwendcode{}\nwbegindocs{3}\nwdocspar
\end{lstlisting}
```

iow, some code for `noweb.sty` ends up in the listings environment 
and is printed verbatim rather than executed. Putting the `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}` between the `<<*>>` and `@` is of course no solution.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Engelbert

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Currently, I maintain the docs and the source code separately, which of course is contrary to literate programming doctrine.

Comment: Well, then you should perhaps explain what "noweb" is, never heared of it. Just explain your issue better ...

Comment: As I mentioned, noweb (https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/noweb/) is a tool for literate programming. Unlike Knuth's original web (and its successor cweb) it is language-independent as it has no pretty-printing ability. Literate programming means that the source code of a program and its docu are maintained in a single file, from which (no)weave extracts the docu and (no)tangle the source code. The idea behind that is that because code and docu are maintained in a single file, they are always updated together, and the docu always reflects the current state of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want can be achieved using a filter. Below you find a hacked `awk` script that at least is capable to handle your file `test.nw` after some minor modification (see below). It can be used as follows:

`noweave -delay -filter 'gawk -f lstfilter.awk' test.nw > test.tex`

And produces

[image: Screenshot of the pdf]

Here the modified file `test.nw` (I just removed `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}` as these are now inserted be the filter):

```
% -*- TeX:UK -*-
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[british,pdftex,twoside,12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%suitable for most modern operating systems
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel,%foreign language support
            xcolor,%handle colours
            css-colors,%defines named web-safe colors
            listings,%typeset computer code
            noweb}%support for literate programming
\frenchspacing
\selectlanguage{british}
\lstloadlanguages{Pascal}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{Cornsilk},
        language=[Borland6]Pascal,
        numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,
        }
\title{Example}
\author{Engelbert Buxbaum }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
@
\maketitle
\abstract{Noweb is a simple to use system for literate programming. It
is suitable for all programming languages, but has no
pretty-printing capabilities. Listings can pretty-print, but has no
literate programming ability. A combination of both would be ideal. }
@
The example code is:
<<*>>=
program HelloWorld;
begin
  write('Hello, World');
  readln;
end
@
Unfortunately, the output is not what was intended.
\end{document}
```

Is this what you want? Here the code for `lstfilter.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    skip_nl = 0
    chunk = -1
}

/^@begin code/ {
    chunk = $3
}

/^@defn/ {
    print $0
    print "@nl"
    print "@end code " chunk
    print "@text \\begin{lstlisting}"
    skip_nl = 1
    next
}

/@end code/ {
    if ($3 == chunk) {
        print "@text \\end{lstlisting}"
        chunk = -1
        next
    }
}

/^@nl/ {
    if (skip_nl) {
        skip_nl = 0
        next
    }
}

{
    print $0
}
```

If you save `lstlistings.awk` in the same directory as `test.nw` you can invoke `test.nw` as shown above. However, I have not tested this script on more complex example. I am just learning to understand how to use `noweb` and how it works. I am not sure if using a filter is the right approach. Is simply failed to understand [noweb.sty](https://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/%7Elehn/noweb.sty) (it can be extracted with `notangle` from [src/tex/support.nw](https://github.com/nrnrnr/noweb/blob/master/src/tex/support.nw), here the pdf [support.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/%7Elehn/support.pdf)).

*Some general note*

I just started this week to use `noweb`. I am still overwhelmed when reading the ["Hacker's Guide"](http://www.literateprogramming.com/noweb_hacker.pdf). I would be very interested to get in contact with other people that are new to noweb and literate programming in general. (I haven't found a mailing list, or did I miss something?)

Comment: Yes, the simple example works with pdfLaTeX (not with XeLaTeX, though). Will work out a more complex example with several chunks and report back. Literate programming is a topic of the Usenet-group comp.text.tex, but I haven't seen lately any discussions relating to it. I have the impression that as logical the ideas of LP are, it has never become really popular.

Comment: Thanks for writing back. About LP I had the same impression. Great concept but a small group of users. However, the book https://pbr-book.org is an impressive example for using LP. They not only can generate a nice Pdf but also HTML. In Chapter 1.1 Literate Programming you can see some features how chunks are linked.

About the hack I provided I am afraid it is limited to your simple example. I am currently exploring whether extending the filter or writing my own latex backend is a better approach.